# Why does SQLite (Python) say that the table "ORGANIZATION" already exists?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

SQLite says that the table "ORGANIZATION" already exists.

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('example4.db')
cur = con.cursor()

# Create table
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE ORGANIZATION
               (ID int, NAME text, SURNAME text, NICKNAME text, ADDRESS chair(250), PHONE 
real, MAIL text, WEB text, INFO chair(250) )''')

# Insert a row of data
cur.execute("INSERT INTO ORGANIZATION VALUES (1, 'John', 'Stockton', 'JS', 'Nip and Tack 15', 
00000000000, 'info@info.xx',' https://www.info.xx', '-' )")

# Save (commit) the changes
con.commit()
con.close()

con = sqlite3.connect('example4.db')
cur = con.cursor()

for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ORGANIZATION ORDER BY ID'):
    print(row)
```

My expected result is to print the row with the Table data:

```
1, 'John', 'Stockton', 'JS', 'Nip and Tack 15', 00000000000, 'info@info.xx',' https://www.info.xx', '-'
```

Comment: You've probably run the program more than once, so the table from the earlier execution still exists in `example4.db`.

Comment: Use : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORGANIZATION …

Answer (score 2):

Every time you run your code, the `CREATE TABLE ...` statement is executed and tries to create the table.
If the table already exists you get the error:

> ...table "ORGANIZATION" already exists...

You can use `IF NOT EXISTS` in the statement:

```
sql = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORGANIZATION(
ID int, NAME text, SURNAME text, NICKNAME text, ADDRESS text, 
PHONE real, MAIL text, WEB text, INFO text)
"""
cur.execute(sql)
```

Also, there is no data type `chair` (I suspect you mean `char` which also is not one of [SQLite's data types](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)), so I changed to `TEXT`.